# Posting JSON Data With PHP cURL

Tags: php, laravel, curl

### Situation

- I want to post JSON data using php cURL into my url `http://localhost/api_v2/url?key=***`

### Here is what I have tried

> POST function

```
public function post(){

    $ch = curl_init("http://localhost/api_v2/url?key=***");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $file_name = 'inventory.csv';
    $file_path = 'C:\\QuickBooks\\'.$file_name;
    $csv= file_get_contents($file_path);
    $utf8_csv = utf8_encode($csv);
    $array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $utf8_csv));
    $json = json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json))                                                                       
    );

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json ); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('data' => $json));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if($status == 200){
        echo "Post Successfully!";
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with laravel, but don't you need to add line `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json );` before `curl_exec($ch)`?

Comment: agreed with Kim, strlen($json) is only to send the string length, but the post data has to be sent to the server in CURL

Comment: you should return something from your webservice controller

Comment: `echo json_encode(['message'=>'Post Successfully!'']); exit()`

Comment: no thanks, I don't think it is necessary :-) you should just read more

Comment: there's no need for the customrequest business. simply setting `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` will set `POST`-mode automatically. customrequest is for the uncommon http verbs, e.g. put, head, etc...

Comment: @KimAlexander Please add your comment as an answer so the OP can accept it :)

Comment: thank you! good luck with your project!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is in this line

> `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('data' => $json));`

Just change it to

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array('json' => $json)));`

Let me know, how it goes !

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with laravel,

but don't you need to add line

`curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json );`

before

`curl_exec($ch)?`

Comment: When I used Postman test go to this url `http://localhost/api_v2/url/post?key=***` I got `Illuminate \ Session \ TokenMismatchException` Do you know why ?

Comment: sorry, I have no idea what is your webservce is like... and what is Postman :-) ?

Comment: can you delete your answer, so I can delete this question Freely .